# Convert an sql query with date_trunc in mongodb type of query

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, date

I have 2 queries where i find very hard to convert them to mongodb type language.
The first one is this:

```
cursor=execute("select date_trunc('day',timestamp1) as day,avg(id13) from timestamppsql where timestamp1 >='2010-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2011-01-01 00:05:00' group by day")
```

And the second one is this:

```
 cursor=execute("select date_trunc('hour',timestamp1) as hour,avg(id13) from timestamppsql where timestamp1 >='2010-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2010-01-01 10:05:00' group by hour order by hour desc")
```

This is what i have wrote for the first one:

```
cursor = mydb1.mongodbtime.aggregate(
  [
      {
        "$match": {
           "timestamp1": {"$gte": datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 00:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                          "$lte" :datetime.strptime("2011-01-01 00:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "null",
          "avg_id13": {
            "$avg": "$id13"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
)
```

I cant find out whats the equivalent date_trunc in mongodb.Any help would be very much appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
cursor = mydb1.mongodbtime.aggregate(
  [
      {
        "$match": {
           "timestamp1": {"$gte": datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 00:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                          "$lte" :datetime.strptime("2011-01-01 00:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {

          "_id": "null",
          #"day":{"$dateToString": { format: "%d", "timestamp1": "$timestamp1" }},
            "day": {
            "$day":  "$timestamp1"},
          "avg_id13": {
            "$avg": "$id13"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
)
```

But also doesnt work.

Comment: you can use $dateToParts and $dateFromParts aggregation functions

Comment: Along with $toDate, since the fields seem to be string?

Comment: @eshirvana  timestamp1 is a datetime object

Comment: @xaroulisgekas great , those functions work with timestamp data type .

Comment: @eshirvana I edited my question,if you have time take a look.I am new to mongodb, still trying to learn how basic things works so dont be harsh on me :p